# Multiple named views associated to CRUD modules

Tags: angularjs, nested, angular-ui-router, view, meanjs

I'm working on a **meanjs** project. I've my home view, and I would **split** it **in several ui-view**

```
<div ui-view="section1"></div>
<div ui-view="section2"></div>
<div ui-view="section3"></div>
```

And each **ui-view** must host his **respective CRUD module** views.

For exemple, if **"section1" ui-view** is associated to the **module "articles"**, I would that "section1" ui-view contains **"list-articles.client.view.html"**, but when I click on "Create a new article" in this list view, I want that the **"create-article.client.view.html"** appears in the "section1" ui-view.

EDIT: I have several CRUD modules (one for articles, one for quick news etc ...), and I want that each module has his own part in an unique page.

I suppose that is possible with **angularjs ui-router** but I don't know how to do it. Thanks a lot for your help.

EDIT 2:

I tried the solution proposed below by Tom, and I'm certainly doing something bad.

In **/modules/core/client/views/home.client.view.html**, I've an ng-include like this :

```
<div ng-include="'/modules/articles/client/views/list-articles.client.view.html'"></div>
```

In **/modules/core/client/config/core.client.routes.js**, I've added this :

```
.state('articles.create', {
  url: '/articles/add',
  templateUrl: 'modules/articles/client/views/create-article.client.view.html'
});
```

(The controller is in the articles modules and defined in the view)

And in **/modules/articles/client/views/list-articles.client.view.html**, the link to the create page is defined like this :

```
<a Href="#/articles/add">create one</a>
```

By the way **#/articles/add** is not well displayed in address bar, I've something like **/#%2F/articles/add**

But the create page is not loaded in the "ng-include" part, but take the place of the home page (I would have it as a partial view).

What am I doing wrong ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Only one ui-view is enough for this case. You can use ui-route plugin, and then by using one `<div ui-view>` element.

In the route define in AngularJS config, you can do something like this:

```
angular.module('app', [
        'ui.router'
    ]).config(config);


    function config($stateProvider) {

        //$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

        $stateProvider.state('default', {

            url: '',
            templateUrl: '/list.html',
            controller: ListController,
            controllerAs: 'vm'

        }).state('list', {

            url: '/',
            templateUrl: '/list.html',
            controller: ListController,
            controllerAs: 'vm'

        }).state('edit', {

            url: '/edit/:id',
            templateUrl: '/edit.html',
            controller: EditController,
            controllerAs: 'vm'

        }).state('add', {

            url: '/add',
            templateUrl: '/add.html',
            controller: AddController,
            controllerAs: 'vm'

        });

    }
```

Also don't forget to define the Controller inside your app as well.

In your html, if you put this type link in it:

```
<a href="#/edit/23">Edit</a>
<a href="#/add">Add</a>
```

It will automatically load your edit.html or add.html when click them.

Of cause you can access the id in edit, like this:

```
function EditController($scope, $stateParams) {

  var id = $stateParams.id;
}
```

If you are going to use multiple views in the same page, I recommend that you use ng-include instead, e.g. in your list.html, you can have:

```
<div ng-include src="'/section1.html'"></div>
<div ng-include src="'/section2.html'"></div>
...
```

And define all routers in one Config file, but inside each sectionNN.html, you can use different view for your purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have several CRUD modules (one for article, one for quick news etc ...), and I want that each module has his own part in a unique page.

Comment: Well, that's only one route for this case, then I suggest you use <ui-view> for routers, and ng-include for each page you want, e.g. <div ng-include="..section1"></div><div ng-include="..section2"></div>